# C++ Most effective way to grab a substring with a value in the middle of a long string

Tags: c++, string, substring

I want to find the most effective way to do something like this:

A big string containing all kinds of data, for example:

```
plushieid:5637372&plushieposition:12757&plushieowner:null&totalplushies:5637373
```

I want to make a function that would have the input to be, let's say `"plushieposition"`, and I would have it find and return the string with `plushieposition:12757`.

The only way I can think of is find the position of `plushieposition` and then scan for `&` and delete the rest. But, is there a cleaner way? If not, what would be the best way to do this in code?

I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding string scan practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::string::find()` to find the starting and stopping positions, and then use `std::string::substr()` to extract what is between them, eg:

```
string extract(const string &s, const string &name)
{
    string to_find = name + ":";
    string::size_type start = s.find(to_find);
    if (start == string::npos) return "";
    string::size_type stop = s.find('&', start + to_find.size());
    return s.substr(start, stop - start);
}
```

```
string s = "plushieid:5637372&plushieposition:12757&plushieowner:null&totalplushies:5637373";
string found = extract(s, "plushieposition");
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/UGlqDG)